# Can not set `task_executor_type`

Tags: postgresql, citus

When I trying to put citus cluster configuration value into `postgresql.conf` file:

```
citus.task_executor_type =  "task-tracker"
```

I got the error:

```
service postgresql restart
Error: Invalid line 637 in /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf: »citus.task_executor_type =  "task-tracker"«
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
```

Tell me please how can I set this configuration value by default?
I am not ready to run `SET citus.task_executor_type TO  "task-tracker"` for each connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you are using double quote instead of single quote and this can be the problem. Try using single quote like:

```
citus.task_executor_type = 'task-tracker'
```